# How to navigate from QR Code Reader to Paticular URL?

Tags: java, android, xml

Project is working fine But my problem is How to navigate from QR Code Reader to Particular URL. what is code to navigate please anyone tell me and help me.
AndroidBarcodeQrExample.java

```
public class AndroidBarcodeQrExample extends Activity {

    static final String ACTION_SCAN = "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void scanQR(View v) {
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_SCAN);
            intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Content:" + contents + " Format:" + format, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/scanner"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="scanQR"
        android:text="QR Code"
        android:textSize="18dp" >
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code to open url in browser is as follow:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("Your url here"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```